# Oracle. How to calculate % in one select

Tags: plsql

Good afternoon, can you help me?

I have a table of "routes"
Me need calculate count all routes, and count routes with "where". And % two from one.

For example:
`select count(routes) from table1`  "~ 150000 items"

`select count (routes) from table1 where distance < 100`  "~ 15000 items"

How to get a number 10%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(CASE WHEN distance < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/count(routes)*100 from table1 where distance < 100
```

Comment: it's a magic, i don't know how it works, but works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally aggregate values:

```
select sum(case when distance < 100 then 1 else 0 end) /
       count(*) * 100 as result
from table1;
```

---

Or (worse), use current queries as subqueries:

```
select
  (select count(routes) from table1 where distance < 100) /
  (select count(routes) from table1) * 100 as result
from dual;
```